# How to show complex html files in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a html doc using GOOGLE DOCS to use in my flutter app.

But It is not working in flutter..It displays a blank screen instead of that html file .

How Can I display html files made with GOOGLE DOCS???

please help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin 
[https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html#-readme-tab-][1]

you can add HTML text in Html widget and it renders Html Text like this

```
Html(
data: """
<div>
  <div id="header_set">
  <h1>Header 1</h1>
  <h2>Header 2</h2>
  <h3>Header 3</h3>
  <h4>Header 4</h4>
  <h5>Header 5</h5>
  <h6>Header 6</h6>
  <hr />
  Below hr
  <b>Bold</b>
  </div>
  """);
```

Comment: already know about plugins.But Plugins only show simple texts.. I want beautiful looking customized texts